# [groovy] pkg-config returns invalid libraries

Tags: ros, groovy-beta

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I recently tried to build my code in ros groove beta, and I get linking errors when linking with roscpp. The problem comes from invalid *.pc script. "pkg-config roscpp --libs" return "... -l/usr/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.so ..." and because gcc does not accept absolute paths for libraries this way it leads to linking error.

Is it intended behaviour of pkg-config ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49538/%5Bgroovy%5D-pkg-config-returns-invalid-libraries/) by [konradb3](https://answers.ros.org/users/2207/konradb3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's ticketed here: https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/300 patched in source and pending a new release.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0